# Kali linux driver QAC9377

Tags: linux, kali-linux, wifi

Acabo de instalar kali linux pero este no me reconoce el la tarjeta del wifi Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377, se que se tienen que instalar los drivers para poder utilizar las tarjetas de wifi pero ya eh intentado con varios metodos pero ninguno me ha sido efectivo, desde instalar el paquete de drivers de Atheros hasta intentar instalarlos individual, desde un inicio en el wifi me ha mostrado el dispositivo no esta gestionado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tal, podrias agregar mas informacion, alguna salida de terminal de algun comando ifconfig o algo por estilo

Comment: Podrias colocar la salida de estos comandos en la pregunta?  1 - `lsmod | grep ath10k` 2 - `ip link show`  3 - `dmesg | grep ath10k`. Es posible que los tengas que correr con sudo.

Comment: podrías colocar eso en texto en la pregunta?

Comment: `wlan0` no es el dispositivo? De todos modos, podrías darnos la salida de este otro comando? `dpkg -l atheros-firmware`

Comment: Y este otro comando: `ethtool -i wlan0`

Comment: que tal amigo, consulta, serias tan amable de poder compartir la salida del comando lspci

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no está relacionada con programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic].